# How to design table structure for Google Calendar like Repeat feature?

Tags: database-design

How to design table structure in a best possible way for Google Calendar like Repeat feature?

Google calendar lets user schedule re-occurrence of an event for indefinite or definite period of time. Now when we do that what is the best way to manage these type of future data in database tables?

For example: I have table called events where I store all regular events which are of non-repeat type and scheduled for some day and time. Now when it comes to events which are reoccurring shall I create a separate table and store it as a template?

For example let’s take it very simple:

```
**Events**
id
title
description
datetime_from
datetime_to
status


**Event_Schedule**
id
title 
description
time_from
time_to
repeats_on (Daily, Weekly, Monthly)
repeat_config ____serialized array or object
```

Fields are not complete but this is just to give some idea and what I can do here is a cron-job or scheduler can create an event every for next occurrence. If it comes to displaying it on calendar it can be done by generating data from `Event_Schedule` table and if user edits data for future event we can store data for that event in `Events` table.
Is it the right way or it can be done in a better way? I could think of storing it in the same table as a template but I find a separate table as better approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database doesn't have to do everything.  Your program code can be responsible for some of the calendar rendering.

Here's one version of the Event database table.

```
Event
-----
Event ID
Event Title
Event Location
Event Description
Event Start Time Stamp
Event End Time Stamp
Repeat Frequency (None, Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly, 
    every nth day (every 3rd Tuesday)
    other odd frequencies 
        (the Tuesday following the first Monday in November, the Sunday 
         following the paschal full moon, which is the full moon that 
         falls on or after the vernal (spring) equinox)
```

Your program would be responsible for going through the event rows of the Event table, seeing which ones have a repeat frequency, and calculating which events would be displayed in the month being displayed.

Basically, your program code would have to calculate the following program object.  This is not a database table.

```
Calendar Event
--------------
Event Date
Event Start Time
Event End Time
Event Title
Event Location
Event Description.
```

You would have a list or array of calendar events for the month being displayed.

Comment: Thanks @gilbert-le-blanc, makes sense. Sorry, I replied after long time but that doesn't change that answer is correct.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc, thank you for the answer. What would happen if we are trying to filter by month? Assume I created a repeatable event. This event repeats every first monday of the month. Now on my frontend I would like to check for events in December. My program would have to filter out all the events in the database that has a frequency and calculate the occurences. Isn't that a intensive calculations?

Comment: @null: There's no general answer.  You could create all the December events on the last day of November with a one-time cron job.  If someone changes the calendar events, rerun the cron job.