# SQL Repeative Event column and using the same in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

Working on booking management application. It allows the user to book the appointment with the doctor. However, a doctor can also able to schedule their activity like `Lunch` `Visiting Hours` and `Vocation`.

Doctor can block activity as recurring based on frequency(daily/weekly/monthly) set in table

Referred [How to design table structure for Google Calendar like Repeat feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068539/how-to-design-table-structure-for-google-calendar-like-repeat-feature)

For example

From 2-Aug-2013 to 31-Aug-2013 , Lunch hour is 2 P.M to 3 P.M

From 14-Aug-2013 to 16-Aug-2013 Vocation

From 2-Aug-2013 to 31-Aug-203 Visiting Hours is 10 A.M to 2 P.M

Also they can able to repeat the same activity for next month.

How do i create table structure for maintaining this data more efficiently.

Here is my approach

`DoctorId` `Activity` `FromDateTime` `ToDateTime` `Frequency`

What would the great way to store the frequency column format in Database in order to easily access in C# code to generate more number of same records for different dates based on weekly/monthly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a table structure that allows users to book appointments with doctors (as opposed to helping doctors manage their schedules, as the question seems to imply both at various times), we don't want to design a table that tells users what the doctor is doing.  A user should only be concerned with whether a doctor is available or not - why do they need to know the doctor is on vacation?  Simply seeing the doctor doesn't have openings for a week or two should be enough.  The below shows a simplified table structure of this: a reference table for the doctor's names, that where `DoctorID` would be the join to show the doctor's name and his/her available hours.

To solve the problem of a user booking an appointment, the user would see the doctors with available times and times would be arranged in a `DATETIME` format so that they could schedule at the appropriate hour with the doctor.  If the doctor isn't available, a time wouldn't appear for them on a specific date (meaning that users select which block of time they want - as shown in the below simple example):

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor(
     DoctorID INT,
     DoctorName VARCHAR(250)
)

CREATE TABLE Appointment(
     DoctorID INT,
     AppointmentHour DATETIME,
     Available BIT DEFAULT 1
)

INSERT INTO Doctor
VALUES (1,'John Doe')
    , (2,'Jane Doe')

INSERT INTO Appointment (DoctorID, AppointmentHour)
VALUES (1,'2013-01-01 10:00:00.000')
    , (1,'2013-01-01 11:00:00.000')
    , (1, '2013-01-01 13:00:00.000')
    , (1, '2013-01-01 14:00:00.000')
    , (2, '2013-01-01 15:00:00.000')

SELECT d.DoctorName
    , a.AppointmentHour
    , a.Available
FROM Appointment a
    INNER JOIN Doctor d ON a.DoctorID = d.DoctorID

DROP TABLE Doctor
DROP TABLE Appointment
```

[SQLFiddle showing this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd090/1).  On the other hand, if you want to build an application for doctors to set their own schedule, that could work in a similar way where doctors would enter the times they will be available and then, as shown in the simple structure above this, the user would see those available times only (when they select a time, the `Available` column turns to 0 - meaning it won't display in the C# application).  For instance:

```
UPDATE Appointment
SET Available = 0
WHERE AppointmentHour = @UserSelection --OR: @DoctorVacation/@DoctorLunch/@DoctorOther
```

Would be an example of the SQL statement when a user selected a time (now, other users can't select it).  For the doctors, there could be a default time, like 8 AM to 5 PM where a doctor is assumed to be available, unless they decided that they won't be (in which case, those times would be removed from the appointment table, or they could also be set to 0 so that they don't appear on the application, so that users can't select those times).